# Create tasks in dynamic in Airflow DAGs

Tags: task, airflow

I want to design an Airflow DAG with several tasks, and I want them execute as this image [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdEbF.png) and the Gantt chart like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiIL3.png) and some descriptions list below:

- A-1, B-1, C-1 must executed in sequential
- A-2 depends on A-1, B-2 depends on B-1 and C-2 depends on C-1
- A-2, B-2, C-2 could be executed in parallel

I have create the desired [DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc7Yi.png) through the code below

```
main_task_list = ["T1", "T2", "T3"]

def decide_what_to_do(table_name, **context):
    if random.randint(0, 100) > 80:
        return tid_prefix_zip_file + table_name
    else:
        return tid_prefix_do_nothing + table_name

def create_tasks_list(table_name):

    tid_call_api = tid_prefix_call_api + table_name
    py_op_call_api = DummyOperator(
        task_id= tid_call_api
    )

    tid_branch_operator = tid_prefix_branch + table_name
    py_op_new_data_come_in = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id=tid_branch_operator,
        python_callable=decide_what_to_do,
        op_args=[table_name]
    )

    tid_zip_file = tid_prefix_zip_file + table_name
    ssh_op_zip_file = DummyOperator(
        task_id=tid_zip_file
    )

    tid_upload_blob = tid_prefix_upload + table_name
    ssh_op_upload_file = DummyOperator(
        task_id=tid_upload_blob
    )

    tid_update_table_setting = tid_prefix_update_table + table_name
    py_update_tables_setting = DummyOperator(
        task_id=tid_update_table_setting
    )

    tid_execute_databricks = tid_prefix_call_databricks + table_name
    db_op_execute_notebook = DummyOperator(
        task_id=tid_execute_databricks
    )

    dummy_op_do_nothing = DummyOperator(
        task_id= tid_prefix_do_nothing + table_name
    )

    # branch 1
    first_pipeline = [py_op_call_api, py_op_new_data_come_in, ssh_op_zip_file, ssh_op_upload_file, py_update_tables_setting, db_op_execute_notebook]
    airflow.utils.helpers.chain(*first_pipeline)

    # branch 1
    second_pipeline = [py_op_new_data_come_in, dummy_op_do_nothing]
    airflow.utils.helpers.chain(*second_pipeline)

    tasks_list = [first_pipeline, second_pipeline]
    return tasks_list

with DAG(dag_id, default_args = default_args) as dag:
    tasks_chain_list = [create_tasks_list(each) for each in main_task_list]

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id="start"
    )

start >> tasks_chain_list[0][0][0]
for n in range(0, len(tasks_chain_list)-1):
    tasks_chain_list[n][0][0] >> tasks_chain_list[n+1][0][0]
```

But these code are not flexible if I want to add more branch to each tasks chain.
Does anyone can help me to improve the code? 
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have try to create the main task A-1, B-1, C-1 and make them as a chain, but I have no idea how to create the A-2, B-2, C-2 in dynamic and attach them to the main pipeline

Comment: OK, great. But you are describing the problem instead of providing code. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).